# Segmentation fault : Bubble sort on link list

Tags: c++, sorting, pointers, linked-list

I'm trying bubble sort on linked list and getting segmentation fault. Am i going right about link list sorting? and debugging shows that there is something wrong with compare function too.

The line where I am getting SEGFAULT is marked.

```
node { 
          string key;
          node *next;
};

void sorting(node &start){
    node *ptr,*ptr1,*pptr;
    ptr=start.next;
    while(ptr){

        bool flag = true;
        ptr1=start.next;
        pptr=ptr1;
        while(ptr1){
            if(flag){           //for starting node
                    flag=false;
                if(ptr1->key.compare(ptr1->next->key)>0){
                    node *temp=ptr1->next;

                    start.next=temp;
                    ptr1->next=temp->next;
                    temp->next=ptr1;
                }
            }else{
                if(ptr1->key.compare(ptr1->next->key)>0){
                    node *temp=ptr1->next;
                    pptr->next=temp;
                    ptr1->next=temp->next;
                    temp->next=ptr1;
                }
            }
            pptr=ptr1;
            ptr1=ptr1->next;
            if(!ptr1->next)  //getting segmentation fault at this line
                break;
        }
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(!ptr1->next)` should be `if(!ptr1)`, because you moved already 1 item forward 1 line above with `ptr1=ptr1->next;`.

Comment: The `node next;` should probably be `node * text;`, note the pointer type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are dereferencing pointer which might be uninitialized.

I guess you should change condition to (since in step earlier you already moved to next node)

```
if(!ptr1)
```

or atleast check whether pointer doesnt point to NULL.

```
if (pt1 && !ptr1->next)
```